# Which granularity for scopes in OpenId connect?

Tags: architecture, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have an Identity Provider, some client applications and a bunch of API resources implemented as RESTful services. Some clients need a single API, others might need several APIs. There might be as well "inter-API-dependencies", e.g.
client needs API X and API X needs API Y.

What is an appropriate scope granularity in this case? Are there any best-practices?

I can image the following solutions:

1. One scope per API: might result in large tokens. Furthermore, in the example above the client doesn't know that it actually needs API Y, too.
2. One scope for all APIs: This would work out (granularity of the user consent isn't a problem). However, the client ends up with a super-mighty access token which it actually doesn't need.
3. One scope per API but using reference tokens: As solution 1, but the tokens remain small. This will result in lots of calls to the introspection endpoint.

Comment: its implementation dependent but one can imagine that the AS adds scope Y whenever scope X is requested; OTOH one could implement the backend in such a way that API X gets its own token to access API Y e.g. using the client_credentials grant

Answer (score 0):

In large enterprise implementations with lots of apps, we often use URIs for scopes and they can be very granular. CRUD for each Application or API is typical.

We also see some Authorization Servers provide Group CNs from LDAP (sometimes 50 or more) as scopes.

Keep [OAuth 2.0 Incremental Authorization](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-wdenniss-oauth-incremental-auth-00.html) in mind also. [Google has an active implementation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth).